# Sort by smalldatetime field produces different results in SQL server and C# (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have a table with a field LastChange which is of type `smalldatetime`. When I sort by ascending order on this field, I get the following:

[image]

I have created an entity corresponding to this in Entity Framework. The type of the `LastChange` field is `DateTime`.

When I execute the same sort operation like this:

```
teams.OrderBy(x => x.LastChange).Select(x => x.TeamID)
```

I get the following result:

```
[0]: 158
[1]: 161
[2]: 159
[3]: 160
[4]: 165
[5]: 163
[6]: 166
[7]: 167
[8]: 168
[9]: 169
[10]: 170
[11]: 171
[12]: 1172
[13]: 162
[14]: 164
[15]: 172
```

Why are the 2 results different? Is it because the `LastChange` values are the same for multiple records? Or has this got something to do with the `smalldatetime` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the LastChange field is exactly the same for several rows. Try these:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY LastChange, TeamID;

teams.OrderBy(x => x.LastChange).ThenBy(x => x.TeamID).Select(x => x.TeamID)
```

In both places and you will obtain exactly the same results. If you don't specify the order for second field SQL will show a random result (for fields not specified), normally is the same but can be totally different.

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard

Answer (score 1):

Both results are correct.
You expect sort order, only by "LastChange" column. Due to precision (to the minutes) of the LastChange column you are getting correct result. Sql or c# doesnt bother of other data in your select example.
Eather add second order parameter or increase input precession for the LastChange column.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because the LastChange values are the same for multiple records?

Yes. Neither c# nor the database will attempt to sort the results further after the LastChange is sorted, so for any values for LastChange that are the same, the rows within that set could be in any order, there will be no consistency - one day they will be ordered like this, and later if the db has reorganised the data in the table they will have a different order. C# might well order things completely differently as a side effect of how the rest of the sorting algorithm works. There is no guarantee that the db and c# will always sort the same way; they will each give up wen the sorting is as good as it can get on LastChange

If you always want data in a certain order, you have to sort it precisely. If the data itself doesn't have anything to order by that is consistent you have to write your own sorting system, or provide additional data

For example if we always wanted this data out of a db table that only contained names:

```
Tim
James
John
```

It's not alphabetical, reverse alphabetical, alphabetical-by-second-character, it's not sorted by length, and so on. There is nothing about this data that we can sort by in terms of the data itself, so we'll have to:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE personname
    WHEN 'Tim' THEN 0
    WHEN 'James' THEN 1
    WHEN 'John' THEN 2
  END
```

Here we've literally converted our data into a sortable thing

TLDR; if you always want data sorted a certain way, you have to be per-row specific. The combination of the columns you sort by, must be unique. As soon as you sort by a set of columns that are not unique, the identical data could come out in any inconsistent, random order

> Or has this got something to do with the smalldatetime type?

No, it affects all data sets being sorted where more than one row has the same value and nothing further helps the sort algorithm choose which of the identical rows should go first